# Flutter get city, country from autocomplete

Tags: flutter

I have an autocompleter for locations and I cannot find where the city name, country and all the details are stored. I want to transfer them to variables such as city = name.city but I cannot find where to take it from.

What the program does, it gets the long and lat of the address. i tried messing around with them but i still couldn't find where they store the details.

Here is my code

```
 import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';

   void main() => runApp(MyApp());

const kGoogleApiKey = "Api_key";

GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: demo(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  demoState createState() => new demoState();
}

class demoState extends State<demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            // show input autocomplete with selected mode
            // then get the Prediction selected
            Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                context: context, apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
            displayPrediction(p);
          },
          child: Text('Find address'),

        )
      )
    );
  }

  Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
      await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

      var placeId = p.placeId;
      double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

      var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

      print(lat);
      print(lng);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GoogleMapsApi` Place Details does not guarantee City name in the response but you can access the Country name and Country ISO Code as following

```
Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
  if (p != null) {
    PlacesDetailsResponse detail = await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

    var placeId = p.placeId;
    String countryIso, countryName;
    double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
    double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

    var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

    for (var adrComp in detail.result.addressComponents) {
      if (adrComp.types.contains("country")) {
        countryIso = adrComp.shortName;
        countryName = adrComp.longName;
      }
    }

    print(lat);
    print(lng);
  }
}
```

Comment: and what do i need to put in pladeDetails to work because now its not working

Comment: and now i get this: 
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 1893): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 1893): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 1893): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 1893): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 1893): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 1893): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

Comment: The problem was `case sensitive`. Try to replace "COUNTRY" by "country"

Comment: do you have any idea why i get this exception?